# How can I stop my ASP.NET webservice from returning xml data?

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, http-headers

I've got a simple ASP.NET webservice. I'm wanting to return a string of json as the result. By default, my webservice is wrapping my json result in some xml.

eg.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://webservice.streetadvisor.com/">{.... json result in here ... }</string>
```

Booo.

- Is there any way i can make my webservice NOT return some xml, but just write my result as raw output?
- Can I define the HTTP-StatusCode in the webservice? eg. `200, 201, 202, 404, 500`, etc?
- Can i define the response type? eg. `application/json`

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily by creating a .ashx handler instead of a normal web service - but at that point you lose a lot of the infrastructure around web services, in particular anything interpreting the data coming from the client in the structured way that SOAP gives you.

Here's an example of [creating an RSS feed](http://www.aspcode.net/Creating-an-ASHX-handler-in-ASPNET.aspx) as a "raw" handler, and here's a [more general tutorial](http://dotnetperls.com/ashx-handler). It's not particularly tricky - if those don't help you much, do a search for ashx and you'll get lots of hits.

I don't know how easy it is to do from a web service project though - I've only done it from a straight ASP.NET web application project. It may well "just work" though - it's worth a try.

Comment: I was afraid this was going to be the answer :) So then I would have to access the querystring or forms directly, for the GET or POST arguments?

Comment: Yup - it that likely to be a problem for you? Do you really have something like SOAP as an input but expect something radically different as output? What is the client here?

Comment: Nope. not a problem. just a bit more plumbing (which i've started doing, an hour or so ago). I'm used to RESTful stuff and LOVE the ASP.NET MVC project type .. so i feel like i'm going backwards with some other projects i'm maintaining. I'm using a rewritting rule to bound the RESTFUL url to a method in my ashx file. Input are simple HTTP-GET or POST, using querystring or post params. output json. Clients are anyone in the public interweb space instead of a closed single 3rd party consumer.

Comment: I haven't done any ASP.NET MVC yet - could you get the rewriting to pass in bits of your URL as method arguments? That would be neat :)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes if im wanting to return JSON i just use a .aspx page with:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
```

Then using a .NET Json framework (like the 1 [here](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)) i create the json i want it to return.

Comment: +1 for simple and easy to get working with jqueryUI's autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
[WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

This worked for me.